# at age 65 should I still keep $190k in traditional IRA mutual funds, or start moving it to non-IRA mutual funds?

Tags: investing, ira, mutual-funds

And, I want to keep the full $190k invested.

What are strategies that I should consider?

Comment: Please tell us **by editing your question, not by writing a comment in response** whether "non-roth IRA" means an IRA but not a Roth IRA (a.k.a Traditional IRA) or something else. There is no need to move IRA mutual  funds into nonIRA mutual funds when you turn 65; you have to _start_ taking Required Minimum Distributions (RMDs) at age 72 (might increase to 75 in a few years time) and pay income taxes on that amount but you do not _have_ to take out _more_  the RMD amount each year, and there are considerable tax-wise advantages to withdrawing only the RMD amount each year.

Comment: @DilipSarwate reminds me of another point: at some point you may want to roll over the Roth portion of your 401k into a Roth IRA, because that escapes the requirement to take an RMD on that money. But that doesn't have to be done until you're approaching age 72, though it can certainly be done earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm following the question, but the standard advice when spending down savings in retirement is:

First spend the non-tax-advantaged savings.

Then, when those approach zero, spend the "traditional" 401k/IRA retirement accounts (no tax paid when put away, but taxed when withdrawn).

Finally, when those approach zero, spend the Roth retirement accounts.

This sequence gets you the most advantage from untaxed growth.